# Web page not loading ASP.NET run time

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am having a problem when running my web app on VS 2019. The pages is working fine but 1 specific page does not load the design the even the back end codes.

It is like this

[image]

I added `<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />` in the web config to view this page. If I remove it, `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden` is showing up and I do not know why because this was working yesterday.

Will really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see a web page in that directory listing.  Just a couple csv files....

Comment: Yes. And I dont know why. When a add another page, it will still be the same with different csv files showing up